# Change Jenkins node label by REST API

Tags: python, rest, jenkins

I need to add/delete Jenkins node label from python script. I tried to do it using REST request but failed with it.
This is the command but not works:

```
curl -k -X POST --user [user]@[password] "https://jenkins-automation.itero.net/computer/JL_private/configure?Labels=lb"
```

Please help me to fix the command or suggest other idea of how to change label from python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use this technique as there is no `configure` API for configuring the node in this way.
If you want to update your node configuration via API you should retrive the `config.xml` of the node using the following API `<JENKINS_URL>/computer/<NODE_NAME>/config.xml`, then update the config file according to the new settings you want, and finally you can POST an updated config.xml to the same URL to programmatically update the configuration of a node.

Example of the `config.xml`:

```xml
<slave>
   <name>My First Agent</name>
   <description/>
   <remoteFS>/var/jenkins </remoteFS>
   <numExecutors>5</numExecutors>
   <mode>EXCLUSIVE</mode>
   <retentionStrategy class="hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always"/>
   <launcher class="hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher">
     <workDirSettings>
       <disabled>false</disabled>
       <internalDir>remoting</internalDir>
       <failIfWorkDirIsMissing>false</failIfWorkDirIsMissing>
     </workDirSettings>
     <webSocket>false</webSocket>
    </launcher>
    <label>windows win10 64bit</label>
    <nodeProperties/>
</slave>
```

In your case you can just update the `<label>` attribute to the new value you want for the node label, and post it to the configuration url given above.